# Automating Production Page Creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a unique question and looking for guidance on where to start looking. I'm new to Rails and Ruby.

I'm looking to take a spreadsheet of information, in this example, it's going to be a list of locations, like cities across the US. And then take that spreadsheet of information and have my rails application create pages for each one of the cities.

My current setup is much like a blog, so I have Posts has a model. Your basic Rails scaffold of posts. Directionally speaking, how would I start looking into methods to write and run a script in production that would automate the creation of Posts based on the spreadsheet list of cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be high level since your question is rather broad. This is how I do it but there's probably dozens of other ways out there.

I use a gem called Roo (https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) which provides read access for all common spreadsheet types. Then you need a method in your posts_controller.rb to process the input.

```rb
# POST /posts/import
def import
  xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(params[:file].tempfile.path)

  xlsx.each do |row|
    i += 1
    next if i == 1 # skip header if necessary
    post = Post.new(field1: row[0], field2: row[1]) # etc.
    if post.valid?
      post.save
      imported += 1
    else
      errors << "Row #{i}: #{post.errors.messages} <br />"
    end
  end
  render json: { success: "#{imported} cities imported.", errors: errors }
end
```

`row` is the row from you spreadsheet and the columns are represented by the array element `row[0]` is cell A of the current row and so on.

Comment: Rather than answer a broad question, ask for clarification to try to coerce the question into a form that fits SO better. Broad questions are off-topic. Clear and concise ones are not. "[answer]" and its linked pages dig into this.